# What determines Firefox tab title text color?

Tags: firefox, colors, browser-tabs, user-interface, title-bar

Sometimes an unfocused tab title is white, and sometimes it is grey. In spite of my best efforts, I have not been able to determine any rhyme or reason behind it. Sometimes a title will change from one to the other. It does not seem to relate to any of the usual suspects like website identity, activity since last view, request method, etc.

Example screenshot:
[image: Firefox tab title colors]

What does the difference signify?

Comment: What operating system and Firefox version are you running?

Comment: The above screenshot was taken of Firefox (75) on OSX

Answer (score 1):

After more experimentation, it appears to be entirely based on whether the title text fits within the tab UI, or whether it overflows off the end. This also explains the "Sometimes a title will change from one to the other" behavior: as I open new tabs, the existing tabs get smaller, and some previously fitting titles will no longer fit in the tab UI.

I can't think of a reason for why this behavior would be useful or desirable. Perhaps it's a bug.